# Australia: Pulse oximeter for overnight sleep study

Tags: sleep, sleep-apnea, pulse-oximeter

I'm looking for a pulse oximeter that can record data overnight and display the results on a Mac laptop or Android app.

This video describes what I'm after:
[Oximiter for Blood oxygen testing: Sleep apnea check - Part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LiNi5hFGzrQ&t)

And this is the product range from ChoiceMMed America:
[ChoiceMMed America Pulse Oximeters products](https://store.choicemmedamerica.com/collections/pulse-oximeter)

The specific product in the YouTube video has been discontinued. Also I live in Australia and prefer buying thing here, since buying overseas takes 4-6 weeks to ship and I get hit with import duty.

Can you recommend a pulse oximeter that's available for purchase in Australia or alternatively on e-bay?